# Define a Python class which can optionally use __slots__ according to a runtime variable

Tags: python

A Python module that I use has recently updated and now all its classes use `__slots__` and so break some functionality I've relied upon. There are a few solutions to this:

1. Copy the code into my own repo with the `__slots__` hacked out. Clearly easiest, but I'd prefer not to.
2. Remove the `__slots__` by monkey patching. I wrote a gloriously hacky function which searches all classes in a module, and any with `__slots__` get replaced by a cloned class with a `__dict__` added and the member descriptors and slots removed.

Solution 2 works, but it feels like a hack. I'd prefer to build a way that allows the module to **optionally turn use of `__slots__` on or off**, and then issue a pull request to the author. It turns out this is pretty tricky.

My first attempt:

module.py:

```
USE_SLOTS = True
class SomeClass(object):
    if USE_SLOTS:
        __slots__ = ()
```

If you can ensure that `USE_SLOTS` is set to False before `module.py` is imported anywhere (and therefore elaborated) then this works, but it is really delicate and breaks unexpectedly.

A factory class is likely ideal, as this would return different classes based on `USE_SLOTS` but the library is peppered with `if obj.__class__ == SomeClass` rather than `isinstance(obj, SomeClass)` so this won't work.

I've spent far too long on this now, so does anyone have a good idea for how to do this?

Comment: What are you doing that `__slots__` breaks? Can you use a [weak key dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html) instead of what you're doing? That's the usual way to emulate adding new properties to an object when you're not in a position to decide what attributes it has.

Comment: Yes I could store all my extra attributes in a totally separate data structure. The reason why I don't want to is twofold. 

1. It would make my code look messy.

2. I actually think that the use of `__slots__` in this case was a bad choice by the module author, but I would be more likely to have luck by providing a compromise rather than just saying "revert it!"

Comment: Why not inheriting from the classes you need to be "writable", and add the slots / variables / methods / whatever you need ?

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but as I said, the library is peppered with if `obj.__class__ == SomeClass` rather than `isinstance(obj, SomeClass)` so it fails.